# How to extend a backbone model with 2 different models

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to use Thorax and Deep Nested Model. Both have different model(Thorax.Model,Backbone.DeepModel)

is it possible to do

```
class MyModel extends Thorax.Model
class MyModel extends Backbone.DeepModel
```

to get both the functionality

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can extend existing model, like:

```
var YourModel = Backbone.DeepModel.extend({
  // your model definition;
}).extend(Thorax.Model);
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to hold the thorax.model's method

Comment: I guess it should have been: ```var YourModel = Backbone.DeepModel.extend({
  // your model definition;
}).extend(Thorax.Model.prototype);```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a new extension to Thorax that has both properties.

```
Thorax.DeepModel = Thorax.Model.extend(Backbone.DeepModel.prototype);
var YourModel = new Thorax.DeepModel.extend(
  /* Your Code Here */
);
```

But if you want to use both of them at the same time all the time I suggest the built in underscore extend:

```
_.extend(Thorax.Model.prototype, Backbone.DeepModel.prototype);
```

Then just use Thorax.Model as you need to.